# batch file to display nicely compare files results

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm looking for a batch code to prepare a file with the differences between two files in a nice way,
Maybe highlight individual lines in a different color,
Does anyone have such a script?

Answer (score 0):

Most command line tools won't produce a file with colouring as they tend to produce plain text files suitable for further processing by other tools. You could try diffutils:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm
...which has various output options if you click through to the documentation. For colouring you could convert the output to html but that might be too much work.

Comment: I am not allowed to download anything...